# mvn test fails to compile the first time

Tags: java, maven

When running `mvn test` after making changes to my project, I get this error:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) on project GenericTests: Fatal error compiling: error: invalid target release: 1.13 -> [Help 1]
```

Running `mvn test` again immediately after, without changing anything in my project, compiles with no problem. Why does Maven just randomly fail in this case?

It's only started happening ever since I installed JDK 13 and changed the compile target in `pom.xml` to 1.13

Comment: change to 13 instead of 1.13 as Nick answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change compile target to 13 not 1.13